# Loop through all unbound controls on a form and clear data

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to loop through all UNBOUND controls on my form and clear their data or reset their values.  I have textboxes, comboboxes and checkboxes.  Every time I try something like this:

```
Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If IsNull(ctl.ControlSource) Then
            ctl.Value = Nothing
        End If
    Next ctl
```

I get a runtime error saying:

> 438 This object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Try `ctl.ControlSource = ""` instead of `If IsNull(ctl.ControlSource)`...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That code loops through *every* control in the form's `Controls` collection.  The collection includes controls, such as labels and command buttons, which are neither bound nor unbound ... so attempting to reference their `.ControlSource` generates that error.

For a control such as an unbound text box, its `.ControlSource` property is an empty string, not Null.

So as you loop through the controls, inspect the `.ControlSource` for only those control types you wish to target.  In the following example I chose text and combo boxes.  When the `.ControlSource` is a zero-length string, set the control's `.Value` to Null.

```vb
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    Select Case ctl.ControlType
    Case acTextBox, acComboBox ' adjust to taste
        'Debug.Print ctl.Name, Len(ctl.ControlSource)
        If Len(ctl.ControlSource) = 0 Then
            ctl.value = Null
        End If
    Case Else
        ' pass
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: Can this be done for locking subform too? Case acTextBox, acSubform

Comment: You could loop through a subform's Controls collection in a similar fashion.  If the subform's Locked property is set, the code could still examine its Controls collection.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: @user1175126 If that comment is related to the question you asked 4 weeks ago, yes you could alter the above code to set the `.Locked` property (instead of `.Value`) of selected control types.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the same thing. However, when I tried this I can still type in the textboxes of the subform.

Comment: I'm unsure whether I understand.  I just set Locked = True on a subform control and Access doesn't allow me to change the values in any of the controls on that subform's form.  I can click in a text box (set focus to the text box), but not change the value that text box contains.

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for. And it works. But I do have a question about how it works. IT checks if the length is 0, and then sets the value to null. I would have thought it would check for NOT 0 and then set to null. If the length is already 0, why does it need to be cleared.  Thanks.

Comment: It checks whether the length of the `.ControlSource` property is zero.  When it is zero, that means it is an unbound control and he wants to set its `.Value` property to Null.