# MS ACCESS 2007 restrict editing to form fields until combobox selection is made

Tags: database

How do i restrict the editing of form fields until a combobox selection is made? I am using MS Access 2007.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: i have not tried anything because i don't know where to begin. I believe i can use some vba code with an event procedure, but i have know clue which one to use or what to use.

Answer (score 0):

On the form, you can start off with all the fields being locked (cannot edit) and disabled (cannot click on them) (you can find those in the property sheet of the form).  Then on the On Change event of the combo box, in VBA, cycle through all the fields and enable them again.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348730/loop-through-all-unbound-controls-on-a-form-and-clear-data) provides code for how to loop through controls on a form. In this example, you would set ctl.Enabled = True and ctl.Locked = False (where ctl is the control you are referencing)

A note, to make sure that the combo box is always changed, I usually put "Choose One..." as the first item of the list.  And check it on form submission to make sure it's not still selected.  That way, it forces the On Change event to fire where it wouldn't if someone used the first option of the list.

Hope that was at least enough to get you started...

**EDIT:** Additional info

In the table design, I put default value of "Choose 1" on the Combo Box and made it the first option.  So when the form comes up, that's what you see.

You can set the Locked property of your memo and date fields to Yes (found in the property sheet under data or you can use the .Locked = True in VBA.

Then, in the on change event of the combo box, click the ... and use the code builder and put something like this:

```
Dim ctl As Control

If Me.Combo77.Value <> "Choose 1" Then

    'Loop through all controls on form
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls

        'Only text boxes, not labels, or combo box ect.
        If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then

            'Unlock the field and allow editing
            ctl.Locked = False
        End If
    Next

End If
```

I tried it out and it works on my little test database.

Here is the MSDN article on the control types: [MSDN Control Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224135%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

To do it this way, I would recommend what I said above and put the first item of the Combo Box something they're not going to choose.

Comment: Thank you but i am new to programming so i need a more direct example/answer. Thank you

Comment: Ok.  What do you have completed in Access so far?  Applicable tables, forms, data entry fields...

Comment: I have a form, a combo box named combo77, and 4 memo fields (current_status, schedule_status, potential_issues, budget_issues) that i would like to restrict editing until combo box selection is made and 3 date fields (ntp, ntp_construct, sub_comp, school_occu)that i would like to restrict editing until combo box selection is made. All appear on the same form. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for that additional info.  See if the additional information I added gives you what you need.  HTH

Comment: Thank you i will give this a try and let you know if i can get it to work.

Comment: Hello Leighbee, it works, i did not add Choose one to my combo box, i replaced with the word Empty in the code: If Me.Combo77.Value <> IsEmpty Then . Thank you for solving my problem